# Volar erring on every intrinsic in a Vue template

Tags: typescript, vue.js, visual-studio-extensions

I am switching to Typescript in Vue and I turned on the Volar extension.  Now every HTML intrinsic (like `section` and `img`) is marked as an error:

```
JSX element implicitly has type 'any' because no interface 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'
```

Not even using JSX...

Answer (score 0):

Why the following works I am not clear, but it does:

```
npm install @vue/runtime-dom
```

I guess it has the interface 'JSX.IntrinsicElements', whatever that is.

Answer (score 0):

In my case this was caused because one of my packages in `node-modules` defined its own global interface `IntrinsicElements`: https://github.com/NightCatSama/vue-slider-component/issues/639. Upgrading the package to `4.1.0-beta.7` resolved the issue.